# How to pass parameter from cron command?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am working on project based on CodeIgniter. 
I have cron command like below:

```
0 5 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/my-project/index.php 'test/mytest'
```

here test is the controller and mytest is function. Now I want to pass a parameter for mytest function from cron command. Say I want to pass a city name.

What adjustment I should made in the cron command to achieve my goal.

Thanks

Comment: you can do it as a command line arg argv argc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass parameters just like in your application.

```
test/mytest/cityName
```

Where cityName is any name of a city.

Your test controller should look something like:

```
class Test extends Controller
{
    .
    .
    .

    function mytest($cityName = '')
    {
        echo $cityName;
    }
}
```